# trying to connection SOAP service using net core / net 5

Tags: xml, web-services, .net-core, soap, .net-5

I am consuming a SOAP service that return order list from market places.

The problem is when I request the orders from SOAP service, result is always null. Tried so many thing but still no change.

**ConnectedService.json**

```
{
  "ProviderId": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedService.Wcf",
  "Version": "15.0.40203.910",
  "ExtendedData": {
    "inputs": [
      "https://api.n11.com/ws/OrderService.wsdl"
    ],
    "collectionTypes": [
      "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2",
      "System.Collections.Generic.List`1"
    ],
    "namespaceMappings": [
      "*, OrderService"
    ],
    "sync": true,
    "targetFramework": "net5.0",
    "typeReuseMode": "None"
  }
}
```

My c# code that user SOAP service

```
var rere = await orderService.DetailedOrderListAsync(new DetailedOrderListRequest
    {
        auth = authentication,
        pagingData = new PagingData
        {
            pageSize = 100,
            currentPage = 0,
        },
        searchData = new OrderDataListRequest
        {                        
            period = new OrderSearchPeriod
            {
                startDate = "01/03/2021",
                endDate = "19/03/2021"
            },
        }
    });
```

and request XML is

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <DetailedOrderListRequest xmlns="http://www.n11.com/ws/schemas">
            <auth xmlns="">
                <appKey>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</appKey>
                <appSecret>XXXXXXXXXX</appSecret>
            </auth>
            <searchData xmlns="">
                <productId xsi:nil="true"/>
                <status xsi:nil="true"/>
                <productSellerCode xsi:nil="true"/>
                <sameDayDelivery xsi:nil="true"/>
                <period>
                    <startDate>01/03/2021</startDate>
                    <endDate>19/03/2021</endDate>
                </period>
                <sortForUpdateDate>false</sortForUpdateDate>
            </searchData>
            <pagingData xmlns="">
                <currentPage>0</currentPage>
                <pageSize>100</pageSize>
                <totalCount xsi:nil="true"/>
                <pageCount xsi:nil="true"/>
            </pagingData>
        </DetailedOrderListRequest>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I catched it from FIDDLER web debugger and the response that coming from SOAP service also catched using fiddler

response XML :

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns3:DetailedOrderListResponse xmlns:ns3="http://www.n11.com/ws/schemas">
            <result>
                <status>success</status>
            </result>
            <pagingData>
                <currentPage>0</currentPage>
                <pageSize>100</pageSize>
                <totalCount>57</totalCount>
                <pageCount>1</pageCount>
            </pagingData>
            <orderList>
                <order>
                    <citizenshipId>TTTTTTT</citizenshipId>
                    <createDate>01/03/2021 17:05</createDate>
                    <id>TTTTTTTT</id>
                    <orderItemList>
                        <orderItem>
                            <approvedDate>02/03/2021</approvedDate>
                            <attributes/>
                            <commission>14.99</commission>
                            <customTextOptionValues/>
                            <deliveryFeeType>3</deliveryFeeType>
                            <dueAmount>142.41</dueAmount>
                            <id>TTTTTT</id>
                            <installmentChargeWithVAT>0</installmentChargeWithVAT>
                            <mallDiscount>7.49</mallDiscount>
                            <price>154.4</price>
                            <productId>TTTT</productId>
                            <productName>TTTTTTTT</productName>
                            <productSellerCode>211131</productSellerCode>
                            <quantity>1</quantity>
                            <sellerCouponDiscount>0</sellerCouponDiscount>
                            <sellerDiscount>4.5</sellerDiscount>
                            <sellerInvoiceAmount>149.9</sellerInvoiceAmount>
                            <shipmenCompanyCampaignNumber>TTTTT</shipmenCompanyCampaignNumber>
                            <shipmentInfo>
                                <campaignNumber>TTT</campaignNumber>
                                <campaignNumberStatus>1</campaignNumberStatus>
                                <shipmentCode>258739698</shipmentCode>
                                <shipmentCompany>
                                    <id>344</id>
                                    <name>Yurtiçi</name>
                                    <shortName>YK</shortName>
                                </shipmentCompany>
                                <shipmentMethod>1</shipmentMethod>
                                <trackingNumber>TTTTT</trackingNumber>
                            </shipmentInfo>
                            <shippingDate>02/03/2021</shippingDate>
                            <sppApproved>true</sppApproved>
                            <status>10</status>
                            <totalMallDiscountPrice>7.49</totalMallDiscountPrice>
                            <updatedDate>06/03/2021 19:00</updatedDate>
                            <version>502</version>
                        </orderItem>
                    </orderItemList>
                    <orderNumber>TTTTT</orderNumber>
                    <paymentType>1</paymentType>
                    <status>5</status>
                    <totalAmount>149.9</totalAmount>
                    <totalDiscountAmount>11.99</totalDiscountAmount>
                </order>
            </orderList>
        </ns3:DetailedOrderListResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The problem that I am facing as you can see above I have successfully sent request and SOAP service send me the result but on net core or net 5 can not deserialized the result that also added above

response result screen shot

[image]

I have tried many different thing but can not solve the return null issues.
Need some help please..

WSDL service URL : https://api.n11.com/ws/OrderService.wsdl

**EDIT :**
some part of WSDL service reference class that generated by net 5 automaticly

```
    /// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.n11.com/ws/schemas")]
public partial class DetailedOrderListResponse
{

    private ResultInfo resultField;

    private DetailedOrderData[] orderListField;

    private PagingData pagingDataField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
    public ResultInfo result
    {
        get
        {
            return this.resultField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.resultField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 1)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("order", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    public DetailedOrderData[] orderList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.orderListField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.orderListField = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

well that is a total waste of time almost 2 days

first image has Order attribute and the second one does not have.

[image]

[image]

so if you are a net core/net 5+ developer this is a life saving tip. Remove the Order attribute from n11 market places Order Service. So you can get the list of orders.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it looks like in .NET 5 but in .net core 3.1 when I was consuming WCF service I had to add some code to make it works

```
public interface IBindingProvider
{
    Binding Get();
}

public class BindingProvider : IBindingProvider
{
    public Binding Get()
    {            
        var transportBinding = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
        var textEncodingBinding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

        return new CustomBinding(transportBinding, textEncodingBinding);
    }
}
```

Binding class of course is from

```
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
```

and in my Startup.cs I had to use

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
 {
      var binding = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IBindingProvider>().Get();
      endpoints.MapControllers();
      endpoints.UseSoapEndpoint<ISomeService>(Constants.SoapHttpRequestPath, binding, SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer);
 });
```

and SoapSerializer is from

```
using SoapCore;
```

Comment: I am using at least 5-6 WCF service at same project and did not need extra code. But this one is realy annoying.

Comment: can you show your classes OrderList and OrderListField

Comment: added auto generated reference file part. and also WSDL service URL so maybe you can generate full of the WSDL references

Comment: I have spend almost 2 days and finally get the solution. Just remove the Order attribute from reference file. added the answer